What is a list of the titles and artists for all of the paintings in the "Art is Dead" videogame?
"Art is Dead" was a video game published in the year 2001.
This videogame introduced children to a number of different famous and historically significant paintings.
For example, there is "The Water Lily Pond" by Claude Monet, 1899.

What is a full list of all of the paintings depicted in "Art is Dead"?




artwork
identification





Gunflowers: Vincent van Gogh - Sunflowers



In the Soup: Andy Warhol silkscreen pastiche of Gian Lorenzo Bernini's buste of Costanza Bonarelli, featuring the iconic Warholian Campbell cans (with the word "Campbell's" replaced by "Warhol".)



Bridge over Rubbish Water: Claude Monet's The Water Lily Pond featuring a detail from his painting Madame Monet in a Japanese Kimono



From Monet's Portrait of Madame Louis Joachim Gaudibert



From Monet's Camille/Woman in the Green Dress



From Monet's Woman with a Parasol/Madame Monet and Her Son



From Monet's Woman with a Parasol facing right



From Monet's The Boat at Giverny



Colour's not Duller: A pastiche of or detail from a work by Piet Mondriaan



Jungle Bungle: I have no idea who this is by, or who or what it's supposed to represent.



They Live: Pieter Breugel the Elder's The Fight between Carnival and Lent



In a Spin: Lionardo da Vinci's Vitruvian Man



Duck or Grouse: Caspar David Friedrich's The Great Enclosure near Dresden



Con-Vince Me: Vincent van Gogh's Bedroom in Arles



A close-eyed version of Van Gogh's Self-Portrait dedicated to Paul Gaugain



Eros Going On: detail from Raphael di Sanzio's Sistine Madonna



Demonized versions of details from Raphael's Triumph of Galatea



Flies by Night: James Abbott McNeill Whistler's Arrangement in Grey and Black No. 1, a.k.a. Whistler's Mum



Moaning Lisa: should I even bother? Terry Gilliamized.



Perhaps a homage/reference to Malevich's Black Square, perhaps just a black field. Used for the puzzle Black is Black.



Clock This: a pastiche (I believe) of collage artworks.



Volcano: detail from Katsushika Hokusai's Fine Wind, Clear Morning, from the Thirty-Six Views of Mount Fuji series



Unstill Life: Paul Cezanne's Still Life with Fruit Dish



I Think Therefore I Am Arme: The Four Philosophers by Peter Paul Rubens



Salmon Rush Die: Ferdinand Hodler's Lake Thun with Symmetrical Reflection



Exverminator: George Seurat's Alfalfa, St. Denis



Bombe Surprise: they look nothing alike, but this could be referencing René Magritte's still copyrighted The Curse



Bottle Job: one of Jean-Baptiste-Camille Corot's Views from the Farnese gardens, Rome (specifically this one)



Screenshots taken from this gameplay video.

"Jungle Bungle" seems to depict a mangrove forest but it isn't a well-known work AFAICT

@Yorik Yeah, exactly. It looks amateurish, or maybe like a backdrop for some theatre piece.

So is "Whistler's Mum" an actual painting? I always thought it was made just for Mr Bean's movie lol

@pinckerman It very much is a real painting, and a serious and moody work by a great artist :)
